# Catching a Request to Open or Create a File and Rerouting it

Tags: c++, file, winapi, monitoring

I downloaded some flash games some time ago to play offline at school if I find myself with no work to do and have a spare. The only problem is that they always attempt to save/load from the application data, and I don't believe the files are created at all, let alone loaded next time I would play it again.

Instead of decompiling each one and finding/changing the save and load location I thought about the Windows API, hooks in particular. Perhaps it may be possible to monitor system requests to create such a file, or open it if it's trying to load, and then tell it to look elsewhere (i.e. my flash drive)?

I don't know if the idea is actually plausible or not, but any solutions, or a solid "It's impossible" would be great.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope some of these help:
[WinAPIOverride32 is an advanced api monitoring software.](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/)
[Deviare API](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/)
[Deconstructing the Poker Client, Part 1](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/deconstructing-the-poker-client-1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll look through these and see if I can get them to do what I want. I had no idea there was software such as this :)